# Install cakephp3 for Mac using XAMPP

Tags: macos, xampp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I installed composer and tried to use

> php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker

to create the bookmarker project in the XAMPP. It showed

```
akephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
```

in terminal. I did some research and uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini, didn't work. Can any one help me? I don't mind using any other tools that can make cakephp3 working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all these months waiting and researching, I figured using virtual box might be a good way doing it. I know it's not a perfect solution but at least it works well on my Mac.

Comment: Anyone who knows how to without using virtual box can also post here! Thanks!